# avoid subquery by using "join" and "group by"

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to avoid a subquery but I'm not able to get the right result:

This is the original query:

```
SELECT T1.IdL, T1.REG, T1.YearIn, T1.URL,
(SELECT Count(*) FROM T2 WHERE T1.IdL = T2.IdL) AS IdL_Count
FROM T1
```

The following is an attempt to avoid subquery but doesn't works becouse the rows where there aren't records in T2 are missing

```
SELECT T1.IdL, T1.REG, T1.YearIn, T1.URL, Count(*) AS IdL_Count
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 USING(IdL)
GROUP BY IdL
```

So I tryed LEFT JOIN but I get wrong IdL_Count: 1 instead of 0

Is there a way to avoid subquery or not?

Comment: Your first subquery is called a correlated subqery and ,if indexed, they are extremely fast.Any reason you want to replace it?

Comment: @Mihai I think you're right. Better if I leave the query as is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid sub query, at least without specified tables structure (indexes etc).
But this query should perform much better

```
SELECT T1.IdL, T1.REG, T1.YearIn, T1.URL, coalesce(T3.count, 0) AS IdL_Count
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT IdL, count(*) as count FROM T2 GROUP BY IdL) T3 on T3.IdL = T1.IdL
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said to Mihai, better leaving the query as is (+1) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you make the COUNT(T2.[somefield]), instead of COUNT(*), it will return 0 when expected. If that does not work, you can do `SUM(IF(T2.IdL IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS IdL_Count` instead.